# cannot bind lvalue error in filling a multidimensional grid

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
int grid[2][2]{};
    for(int i{};i<4;i++){
        cin>>*(grid+i);
    }
```

I am trying to input values in a 2x2 grid. How should I do it correctly and what was going wrong.

Comment: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 2; ++j) if (!(std::cin >> grid[i][j])) throw "oops";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple possible implementation for your problem:

```
int grid[2][2];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        std::cin >> grid[i][j];
    }
}
```

You could also use range-based for loops, if you plan on changing the dimensions of the grid frequently:

```
int grid[2][2];

for(auto& row : grid){
    for(auto& point : row){
        std::cin >> point;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's working for me.  Could you also tell what was going wrong in my code

Comment: @AjayTyagiB18ME003 A couple things. First of all, grid isn't a pointer variable, so you can't dereference it. In your code I noticed you did `*(grid+i)`, which isn't valid for an array. You can access array variables but subcripting them (grid[1][2]), but you have to provide both indices to access a variable for a 2d array.

Comment: thanks azam, I also read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-array-array-pointer/ to understand the point more clearly